# Phpmyadmin lists another domain name

Tags: shared-hosting

In phpmyadmin, the user shows as [myusername]@[someone else's domain].

We are on a shared server and it appears that this domain might be another one on our server. Our hosting company has assured us that this is not a problem stating that it is phpmyadmin doing a reverse DNS lookup.

Is there anyting to worry about here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be OK as long as you are granting access to your IPs only not to others also.